# When using Firebase Authentication service, how to throw error when login by Facebook/Google with no existing account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm developing a `Flutter` app using `Firebase Authentication service`.

The following `Flutter` plugins are used:

1. [Firebase_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth)
2. [Google_sign_in](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in)
3. [Facebook_login](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login)

The login flow is:

1. Login with either Facebook, Google or Email&Password
2. If account has already been created, logged in
3. If not, throws error

This is possible if the logging method is Email&Password. In `Firebase_auth` plugin, there are two separate methods for Email&Password scenario: `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. When the sign in method is called with a non existed account, it will throw a `wrong id/password` error.

However, for the Facebook/Google login method, the plugin only provides
`signInWithFacebook` and `signInWithGoogle` and the way they work is that the first time user uses facebook/google account to sign in, `Firebase` will automatically create an account and return the newly created account. (no separate `sign up` and `sign in` process)

I also read on the [Firebase doc for Android Google Sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

> After a user signs in for the first time, a new user account is created and linked to the credentials—that is, the user name and password, phone number, or auth provider information—the user signed in with. This new account is stored as part of your Firebase project, and can be used to identify a user across every app in your project, regardless of how the user signs in.

So, my question is: If user logins with Fb/G account that has not yet been used to register with my app on `Firebase`, how do I make `Firebase authentication` throw error instead of automatically create a new account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malcolm from the Firebase team here! Great question.

Given the functionality that currently exists in the [open source Flutter plugins](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth), you can likely get the result you desire by using the method #fetchProvidersForEmail(). Here are the logical steps you'll follow for the federated IDPs:

1. Do normal sign in the with IDP and get a token.
2. Parse that returned token for the user's email (usually using a JWT parsing library).
3. Call #fetchProvidersForEmail() with the extracted email.
4. If the providers that come back for the email are empty, then it's a new account. Otherwise, it's an existing account.

Alternatively, you could update the Flutter plugin to return more of the [AuthResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult), which includes whether or not the user is new. If the user *is* new, then you just call [FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser()#delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#delete()) and throw whatever error you wanted. (Which you would also have to add to the plugin).

Comment: Thank you! I thought the `Dart plugin` already implemented all the SDK's methods. I think your answer is clear enough for me to implement the concrete solution myself.